# How do you say "no backsies" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, estados-unidos

"No backsies" it what kids say in the U.S. when playing the game 'tag' (pilla-pilla / jugar a pillar), to prevent the person that is "it" from tagging you right back. Or, it can be said when giving a dubious "gift" such as a piece of trash to a classmate or your brother.

Is there an equivalent in Spanish?

Comment: Do you want to explain what tag is in case readers do not immediately know? In the UK we normally say "no returns" I think but it is several decades since I last played tag.

Comment: I was about to say the same: I have not the minimum idea what is "tag" as a game. To be honest, I haven't understand like 90% of the question: I suppose that "_a dubious gift such as a piece of trash_" is not literal so "_a piece of trash_" is just an expression meaning a really bad gift?

Comment: Just to see if I have got it right. The tag game is what here in Spain we call "pilla pilla" or "jugar al pillar". One kid has to run after the others and touch them, then the roles of chaser and chased are inverted. I take it that "no backsies" is said when one kid touches another, then the other touches him back immediately, returning to him the chaser role in no time. Is the sentence said to indicate that that situation is not valid? Is that the right context?

Comment: From the question and the definition of the game, I'd say that a translation would be in the line of "*no vale devolver*" or something like that.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo you say it as you touch the person to stop them re-tagging you. At least that is what we do in the UK.

Comment: FWIW, my kid's preschool teacher said this: "it's more of a sentence 'no se vale regresarla' I hope this helps. "

Comment: @Fedorelsátrapa You should make that an answer, it's what a kid would say most probably, although we didn't do that type of things, as far as I remember we just couldn't do that, the one who was touched had to count again so the rest of the kids had time to run :P

Comment: In Chile the game is called "pinta" or "tiña". One possible translation for "backsie" is **_chicle_** ("gum"), when you are touched and you immediately touch the other, which is generally considered a cheating. There is no rule for "no backsies" during the game, but participants do agree before they play. _"Bueno, juguemos a la tiña, pero sin chicle"_. As you observe, this is absolutely regional and depends on the version of the game. I do not think there is a single correct answer.

Comment: In Paraguay we say "sin vuelta".

Comment: In Buenos Aires the game is called *mancha*, and we said *no vale mancha con mancha*

Comment: It really looks like since there are differences in US and UK english, that asking how to say this in Spanish, with all the different countries, is too broad of a question. Should I update the question or leave as is?

I am most fond of sin chicle and sin vuelta since they seem simple for kids to remember, but also would be curious as to Mexican / Mexican American Spanish since here in the pacific northwest would be most common.

Thanks for all the answers, though, it's been enlightening and entertaining!

Comment: In Spain, children would say *no vale devolver*. Well, at least in the parts of Spain that I know better. If I willingly give a trash gift to a friend (as a joke, for instance), I might also say *no vale devolver*. He would probably ignore that and take revenge at the first opportunity, of course :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En México, en el juego de **la traes/quemados/la roña** se dice **no vale chicle**.

El juego es similar al de **[tú la llevas](http://www.juegostradicionalesaragoneses.com/juegos/tula.htm)** en España. Según el enlace se dice **no vale devolver la tula**. Sería interesante que algún español confirmara esta información.

Dejo unos enlaces relevantes:

- [Juegos de persecución](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juego_de_persecuci%C3%B3n)
- [Juegos mexicanos](http://juegostradicionalesmexicanos.blogspot.mx/2010/01/juegos-para-correr.html)

Comment: ¿Qué es la traes/quemados/la roña? Sería interesante que añadieras referencias a este juego para los que (como yo) no sabemos a cuál te refieres. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo que es como el "tú la llevas", sólo que en vez de llevarla se trae. :)

Comment: @CarlosAlejo pues tampoco conozco el "tú la llevas" :O ¡Necesito revivir la infancia!

Comment: Correcto @fedorqui, cualquiera de los tres sirve como nombre alternativo del mismo juego. Solo que en México **tu la traes** no **la llevas**

Comment: Creo que es lo que en Argentina conocemos como "la mancha". Un niño es la mancha, y persigue a los demás hasta conseguir tocar a uno, que pasa a ser la mancha, hasta que logre tocar a otro.

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que sé, a este juego se le llamaba "la pilla", porque consistía en que quien "la lleva" tiene que [pillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T0BTFmP#MPUM5eK) a los demás.
Cuando pillabas a alguien decías "*¡Pillado/a!*" o "*¡La llevas!*", y directamente añadíamos "***¡No vale de vuelta!***". Se sobreentendía que se refería a... lo que fuese esa cosa que llevaba quien "la" llevaba a partir de ese momento.

También se aplicaba a otros juegos similares como "la peste", parecido a la pilla e imagino que también al mencionado de la roña, solo que a la peste se jugaba cuando ciertos olores invadían de improviso el aula o sitio en el que estuviéramos. La dinámica era parecida: tocabas a otro y decías "*¡La peste!*", y a continuación cruzabas dos dedos de una mano y hacías un gesto como de clavarlos en tu brazo contrario y decías "*¡Me vacuno!*", con lo cual se suponía que ya no te la podían volver a pasar. Pero siempre había alguno/a que intentaba devolvértela antes de que te vacunases, y es entonces cuando se recurría, con aire enfadado, al consabido:

> ***¡¡No vale de vuelta!!***

---

Oops, just noticed the question is in English.

As far as I know, this game was called "la pilla" because the one who was "it" had to *grab* the other players. To grab in Spanish can be said as [pillar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T0BTFmP#MPUM5eK).
When you grabbed someone, you said "*¡Pillado/a!*" (meaning "Grabbed!" or "Tagged!") or "*¡La llevas!*" (both meaning "You are it!"), and immediately we added:

> ***¡No vale de vuelta!*** (*No backsies!*).